# Which of the participant states was benefited in the long run by the Congress of Vienna?

Tags: diplomacy, napoleonic-wars

Congress of Vienna took place in 1814-1815 aiming to restore stability in Europe after the Revolutionary and Napoleonic wars. Each state/kingdom sent their diplomat(s) to the congress in order to negotiate and gain most for the state.

It is true that Metternich was the mastermind, and Austria (re)gained control of parts of Italy, but they lost them within half a century during Italian unification. So which of the great European powers enjoyed the most benefits from the Congress in the long run? Or was it none of them, achieving the "Balance of Power" as it had hoped to?

I can't exactly quantify "benefits", but it should include economic, or territory-wise benefits, or getting access to some key strategic locations or strategic benefits.

Comment: Short answer: Britain and Prussia, I would say.

Comment: I think "the long run" is rather undefined... you could say that the Viena Congress provoked the 1830s revolutions, which caused 1848s revolutions, which were crucial for Napoleon III rise to power, which developed into the Franco-Prussian, which was one of the sources of WWI... and end with "USA as super-power and China as local, rising power". Could you stablish a timeframe? 25 years? 50 years? 100 years?

Comment: @Drux what part of the Congress benefited Britain? I would say that, for the most part, Britain ignored Europe and focused in its colonies. That, and (mostly) its industrialization was that caused Britain to become an Empire, but those were not consequences of the Congress (at least, as far as I know).

Comment: @SJuan76 Didn't the peace with and, comparative stability within, Europe allow Britain to concentrate on its trade and empire rather than draining its resources in wars?

Comment: From one perspective, every inhabitant of every nation was benefitted; the Congress of Vienna decreased the probability of another world war.  Until you can define "benefit" in a way that will allow me to compare the benefits of two or more countries, this is an opinion question. Semantically this is equivalent to "Which woman is the prettiest?"

Comment: I don't know how to quantify this, but it's not completely vague either, right? For example, France clearly didn't benefit as much as Prussia, and so on. I guess economic or territory-wise benefits would be one way of looking it, though that's definitely not the only criterion.

Comment: It was the 19th century as a whole which benefitted. One of the reasons for the stratospheric growth in living standards in Europe in the 19th century (1815-1914) was that it was a century of peace (well almost - there was the Crimean War, and the 1848 revolutions, I suppose) in which industry could develop and prosper.

Comment: @taninamdar - France got readmitted to the comity of nations of Europe, and could thus develop in peace for a couple of generations, which when contrasted to the century or so of continual wars under kings and emperors looks pretty good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prussia was a great beneficiary. It had been a rising power for most of the 18th century, but its progress was set back by the Napoleonic wars, regime. Prussia was a "conservative" state that benefited for Metternich's reactionary tendencies, but the most dynamic of conservative states that also included Russia, Austria-Hungary and the Ottoman empire. As such, it was an acceptable core for the newly emerging German power.

The Metternich system seemed to benefit conservative Russia, but that country soon lost in dynamism what she gained in political stability. France was something of a loser; from a fundamentally offensive posture since the 15th century, she went more and more on the defensive as the 19th century wore on. Britain gained from the balance of power and the hobbling of the more conservative states

Comment: What is a "conservative" state?

Comment: @taninamdar: A state that discourages change, that doesn't allow the "rocking of the boat."

Comment: @taninamdar - Generally in the context of that era, we speak of countries being [Liberal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_liberalism) or "Conservative" (or often "Reactionary"), based on how democratic they were (often specifically how large a % of their population could vote for their leaders). So here I would assume "Conservative" means a more autocratic state.